# LocationRequest setInterval is not working properly in android

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

I have created two instances of `LocationRequest` with different interval time and i am using the `fusedLocation Api` for location update. In location update if user is not moving i am removing the location updates by using removeUpdates command and requesting the new location update using another instance of location request and similarly doing he same for if user is moving . But after some time i am getting the location updates for every 1 sec(when user is not moving) and if user is moving  i  am getting the location updates for every 2 secs.And  also sometimes i get updates too late.

I could not figure out why i am getting location updates for random interval time period which i have never set. I am assuming that it should provide me location update accordingly the set interval time .

Can anyone help me out with this please. thanx in advance :)

**Note**: No other location requesting app is running and `fastestinterval` is same as `setInterval` .

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected (@Nullable Bundle bundle){

    //here mShortLocationRequest, mLongLocationRequest are instance of  LocationRequest
    //and SHORT_INTERVAL = 5000;
    //LONG_INTERVAL = 20000

    mShortLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mShortLocationRequest.setInterval(SHORT_INTERVAL);
    mShortLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(SHORT_INTERVAL);
    mShortLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mLongLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLongLocationRequest.setInterval(LONG_INTERVAL);
    mLongLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LONG_INTERVAL);
    mLongLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mShortLocationRequest, this);
    }

}


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged (Location location){

    //logic for isMoving here...

    if (isMoving) {
        //location updateds with long interval removed
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // here i am setting the short interval time by passing the mShortLocationRequest
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mShortLocationRequest, this);
            isShortIntervalSet = true;
        }
    } else {
        //location updateds with short interval removed
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // here i am setting the short interval time by passing the mShortLocationRequest

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLongLocationRequest, this);
            isShortIntervalSet = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please try to explain your question clearly.this line "if user is not moving i am removing the location updates and requesting the new location update using another instance of location request and similarly doing he same for if user is moving ." is creating confusion.

Comment: as you can see in my code of `onLocationChanged` for updating the interval time of LocationRequest i have used two instances of LocationRequest. So in onLocationChanged i am checking whether user is at same location or not. if user is at same location i am removing old locationRequest(i.e shortLocation) using   `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);` & requesting new location update using   `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLongLocationRequest, this);` by passing new  mLongLocationRequest to the fusedApi

Comment: i dont know u get it or not. actually i want to know that why i am getting location updates for random time interval. when i have clearly set interval time to the 5 secs and 20 secs in code.